# How to set a welcome message from my login acitivity to profile activity?

Tags: android

below is my activity_profile.xml where the user's info will appear.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg8"
tools:context="com.example.bencel9314.petcareinformationsystem.ProfileActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivProfilePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/catprofile"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/welcome_message_layout" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivGallery"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_message_layout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to your Profile"
        android:textColor="#006"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etContactNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmailAddress"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etEmailAddress" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my ProfileActivity.java

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView ivGallery, ivProfilePicture;
GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;
final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 12345;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);


    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailAddress);
    final EditText etContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContactNumber);

    galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());

    ivGallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);
    ivProfilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePicture);

    ivGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Dispatch incoming result to the correct fragment.
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param resultCode
 * @param data
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
            String photopath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photopath).requestSize(1200, 800).getBitmap();
                ivProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Something went wrong while choosing photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

What codes do I need to use to make a Welcome Message showing the User's Name, Username, email address and contact number in the profileactivity.java?

I tried the tutorials from youtube but most of them does not work....

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to pass data from one activity to another uses intents. 
From the login activity do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("WELCOME", "Welcome message goes here!");
startActivity(intent);
```

And then from the profile activity you can access the message in the intent:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    String welcomeMsg = "";

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        welcomeMsg = extras.getString("WELCOME");
    }
    else {
        welcomeMsg = "Default welcome message!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you could achieve this.

1. Passing the values through an intent.

Create a Bundle object and add it to the intent for starting the ProfileActivity:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(WELCOME_MESSAGE, message);
 bundle.putString(USER_NAME, name);
 bundle.putString(FULL_NAME, fullname);
 bundle.putString(EMAIL, email);
 bundle.putString(ADDRESS, address);
 bundle.putString(PHONE, phone);
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

then in your Profile Activity in the onCreate method, you can retrieve your values:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null) {
String name = bundle.getString(USER_NAME);
String fullName = bundle.getString(FULL_NAME, fullName);
String email = bundle .getString(EMAIL);
String address = bundle.getString(ADDRESS);
String address = bundle.getString(PHONE);
String message = bundle .getString(WELCOME_MESSAGE, "default message");
}
```